# ERROR on dialog creation in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, settext, findviewbyid, r.id

I am getting this error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

I tried changing the setContentView after setting the Text but with no luck.
I can't find what I am doing wrong even thought I searched.

Here is my dialog creation. The error comes up when I set the text from the textview.

```
public void forgetDialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); // Context, this, etc.

        dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title2);

        //  dialog.setOnDismissListener(dialog.dismiss(););
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        TextView txv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_info);
         txv.setText("");
        txv.setText("You forgot to add the ingredients!");

        dialog.show();
        btn_dialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok) ;
        btn_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the xml I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/dialog_text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_info">



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@color/dialog_ok_bgcolor"
            android:text="Ok, got it"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Step**
Write two separate file xml, one for the layout of the activity (*activity.xml*), one for the layout of the dialog (*dialog.xml*). Make sure that your *dialog.xml* contains the TextView and the Button that you need.

**Second Step**
Declare
`Button btn_dialog;
 TextView txv;`

before the code that I put in the next step.

**Third Step**
Try this code, I tried it and it worked.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    forgetDialog();
}

public void forgetDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); // Context, this, etc.
    dialog.setTitle("Title");

    //  dialog.setOnDismissListener(dialog.dismiss(););
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    txv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_info);
    txv.setText("");
    txv.setText("You forgot to add the ingredients!");

    dialog.show();

    btn_dialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok);
    btn_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

I think that the error were:
1) the management of the layouts;
2) you have forgotten to tell in which View you want to find the id of the TextView.

Comment: Yeap it was the number 2. I put the dialog in front of findViewById and it worked! Thank you!